# 'Specified condition "$(PackageAsSingleFile)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

The visual studio 2012 on my PC get the following error message when preview in the "Public Web". I need to restart VS to get rid of the error message.

> Invoke build failed due to exception 'Specified condition "$(PackageAsSingleFile)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets'

What caused the error?

Answer (score 219):

I'm not sure what causes it, but restarting VS 2012 fixed it for me.

Comment: mucking with the web deploy settings caused this for me, and restarting VS was also the fix.

Comment: @CodeGrue I was doing the same, went to publish, got this, restarted VS and magic works.

Comment: Restarting VS 2012 is not a way. After 3 publishing this error show again.

Comment: Anyone has a more structural solution to this? Restarting works, but I keep getting this error occasionally..

Comment: I seemed to get this after adding a nuget package, maybe a point for investigation?

Comment: @ThomasHarris - do you know which package(s) you just added?

Comment: I started to debug a program in VS2013 (Update 2), then cancelled with Ctrl + Break. From that point, I started getting this error whenever I attempted to build, publish or debug the project again. Restarting VS2013 resolved it.

Comment: @RustyDivine I'm pretty sure it was the Microsoft BCL nugets.

Comment: I notice I generally get this when I try to do the "web publish preview".

Comment: This seems to be an issue with NuGet, when updating or uninstalling packages. I'm running VS2013 Ultimate, but I'm running so many plugins and addons that debugging becomes a war of attrition; especially since restarting VS solves the problem. For issue research purposes, this occured for me when uninstalling Nuget Package TinyMCE.MVC.JQuery and updating to TinyMCE4.MVC.JQuery.

Comment: I am also having this problem but I get it when reinstalling NuGet packages. Restarting VS has no effect, but deleting the .suo files did fix the problem for me however.

Comment: This also worked in VS2017: After I got this error due to a known issue with A dependency, switching to a known working git branch did not resolve it until restarting VS.

Answer (score 46):

Restarting VS usually helps, but when it doesn't - try deleting `.user` and `.suo` files, as per this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16223645/913845

This does not always work, however if you skip "Preview Deployment" it is less likely to fail.

Probably it's the solution to the entire class of **evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.** Visual Studio problems. Something for VS team at MS too look at?

Comment: Skipping "Preview Deployment" fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I've found a very very weird (and working) workaround for this type of deploy issues, if you have tried closing & opening VS with no luck, try to close all open document prior to the publish process.
weird huh? :)

so the complete fix-it guide for this type of issues would be like the following:

1. Try "Clean" then rebuild
2. If it's still not publishing, try closing & reopening your project again
3. Still no luck? try closing VisualStudio but this time delete all the *.user & *.suo files, then open up your solution again and give it a try.
4. Finally if all these steps are not working, try my newest trick, close all the opened document and give it a try

let me know if this has helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

One common scenario that also raises that error is when you have files referenced on your solution that are missing.

So excluding those from the solution will fix it.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are hitting this issue using Azure Functions then you need to specify that project outputs an executable in your .proj file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Source: https://pmichaels.net/2022/02/12/isolated-azure-function-in-net-6/

Answer (score -4):

You need to run Visual Studio "As Administrator". The path specified requires administrative authority for writing.

Comment: actually the error will go if restart Visual studio even without running as administrator.

Comment: This has no effect whatsoever.