# CleanWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder error makes my project no longer load

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Using VS2012 I created a dynamic data project. It all worked and then I started configuring the web deployment settings. I am not sure what setting I changed exactly as there was no error. However when I try and load the solution I get the following error for the project and it will no longer load.

```
Specified condition "$(CleanWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
```

I cannot see CleanWPPAllFilesInSingleFolder in the csproj file. Any ideas on how to fix this so that I can load the project once more?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

I just had this issue as well. Try the following:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete your .user and .suo files
3. Re-open the solution.

This worked for me.

Comment: for the bleary eyed speed readers: that is close *Visual Studio* Not the solution!

Comment: I've just stumbled upon this issue in VS2012, and simply closing and reopening VS solved the problem for me, no deleting necessary.

Comment: I find this issue is caused by using the `Preview` feature of the new Publish window.  If I skip the preview, it seems to work.

Comment: Similar answer here: http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/02/visual-studio-error-cleanwppallfilesinsinglefolder-evaluates-to-instead-of-a-boolean/

Comment: Also here. For me, I'd opened VS 2013, changed a config and immediately went to publish to Azure. When I did the preview, it failed with the error mentioned. Then, I couldn't build. The trick is to do a Rebuild BEFORE you publish, and it works.

Comment: I'm still encountering this with VS 2015. I find that if I close the solution, delete the .user file, then reopen the solution, then the Preview button will work once. After that it will fail every time (irrespective of doing a Clean/Rebuild) until I close the solution and delete the .user file again.

Comment: IN addition to all this, I found that the value for one of these was False while everywhere else in the file it was false (lower case) AND it was not on a line by itself with leading blanks. Here is what one of these looks like in my csproj file for VS2013:
     <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <TransformWebConfigEnabled>false</TransformWebConfigEnabled>
    <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>false</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
Removed blanks, lowercase false, and put on one line, publish problem mitigated.

Answer (score 7):

I've found a very very weird (and working) workaround for this type of deploy issues, if you have tried closing & opening VS with no luck, try to close all open document prior to the publish process.
weird huh? :)

so the complete fix-it guide for this type of issues would be like the following:

1. Try "Clean" then rebuild
2. If it's still not publishing, try closing & reopening your project again
3. Still no luck? try closing VS but this time delete all the `*.user` & `*.suo` files, then open up your solution again and give it a try.
4. Finally, if all these steps are not working, try my newest trick, close all the opened document and give it a try
  5.

let me know if this has helped you :)

Comment: #1 (**Clean Solution** in VS's **Build** menu) was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 4):

I closed and re-opened my solution.  I'm inclined to believe it's a defect in the Preview feature as that was the only thing I did differently before it started happening.  I haven't been able to reproduce it since, however.

Answer (score 3):

All I did was close Visual Studio then Reopened it. Done

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out that IIS was not installed on the destination server! Installing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after removing all *.user and *.suo I had to restart VS.